# Type error when combine "React Toastify Redux" react project

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, toast

I am trying to add

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify-redux#toast-base-option

When I trying to combine the reduces I am getting the below error

```
    No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<{ basketsReducer: Reducer<any, AnyAction>; toasts: Toast[]; }, any>): Reducer<{ basketsReducer: Reducer<any, AnyAction>; toasts: Toast[]; }, AnyAction>', gave the following error.
    Type '(toastList: Toast[], action: ToastAction<any>) => Toast[]' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<Toast[], any>'.
      Types of parameters 'toastList' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type 'Toast[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Toast[]'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Toast[]'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<{ basketsReducer: Reducer<any, AnyAction>; toasts: Toast[]; }, AnyAction>): Reducer<{ basketsReducer: Reducer<...>; toasts: Toast[]; }, AnyAction>', gave the following error.
    Type '(toastList: Toast[], action: ToastAction<any>) => Toast[]' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<Toast[], AnyAction>'.
      Types of parameters 'toastList' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type 'Toast[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Toast[]'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Toast[]'.ts(2769)
index.ts(7, 18): The expected type comes from property 'toasts' which is declared here on type 'ReducersMapObject<{ basketsReducer: Reducer<any, AnyAction>; toasts: Toast[]; }, any>'
index.ts(7, 18): The expected type comes from property 'toasts' which is declared here on type 'ReducersMapObject<{ basketsReducer: Reducer<any, AnyAction>; toasts: Toast[]; }, AnyAction>'
```

May I know why I am getting this error, my other reducers are working fine, can find the code snips to my combine reducer

```
import { toastsReducer as toasts } from 'react-toastify-redux';
import basketsReducer from './basketsReducer';

 export default combineReducers({
    basketsReducer,toasts
 })
```

Comment: Toasts may not be a proper reducer. Need more code to help.

Comment: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify-redux#toast-base-option library and followed documentation

Comment: Since the toast project is 2 years old and no else complained of this error on github recently, either no one else uses the project or some part of your incorrect. I'm leaning towards the higher probability that something is wrong with your code so please post more code.

Comment: Actually I haven't done much other than installing the "react-toastify-redux" and adding it to my existing combine reducer, I am using type script in the project and if I removed the "basketReducer" error is still exist

Comment: Set it up on codesandbox. Should be simple since you have setup much.